# Iterating through javascript object to see text (like python requests.text)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

We're currently trying to transfer code from a Python web scraper to a Node.js web scraper. The source is the Pastebin API. When scraping, the response is a javascript object like this:

```
[
  {
    scrape_url: 'https://scrape.pastebin.com/api_scrape_item.php?i=FD1BhNuR',
    full_url: 'https://pastebin.com/FD1BhNuR',
    date: '1580299104',
    key: 'FD1BhNuR',
    size: '19363',
    expire: '0',
    title: 'Weight Loss',
    syntax: 'text',
    user: 'loscanary'
  }
]
```

Our Python script uses the requests library to request data from Pastebin's API and to get access to the actual body of the paste, in addition to the parameters above, we loop through the first entry and retrieve its text value. Here is an excerpt:

```
response = requests.get("https://scrape.pastebin.com/api_scraping.php?limit=1")

parsed_json = response.json()
print(parsed_json)
for individual in parsed_json:
    p = requests.get(individual['scrape_url'])
    text = p.text
    print(text)
```

This brings back the actual body of the paste(s), which we can then search through to scrape for more keywords.

In Node, I don't know how to retrieve the same text value of the "scrape_url" parameter in the same way as I can with requests.text. I've tried using axios and request but the furthest I can get is accessing the "scrape_url" parameter with something like this:

```
const scrape = async () => {


try {
    const result = await axios.get(pbUrl);
    console.log(result.data[0].scrape_url);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

scrape();
```

How could I get the same result as I can with .text from the Python Requests library and in a loop?

Comment: [`result.data.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I completely forgot about forEach to loop through the items. But this doesn't answer how I can get access to the body of the scrape in the url like we can with the requests.text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it (as mentioned by [Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) )

```
const scrape = async () => {

try {
    const result = await axios.get(pbUrl);
    result.data.forEach(async (individual) => {
       const scrapeUrl = individual['scrape_url'];
       const response = await axios.get(scrapeUrl);
       const text = response.data;
       console.log("this is the text value from the url:", text);
    });



  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

scrape();
```